# xml comments strange behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've encountered very strange behavior of xml comments in c#
///

after building the assembly, not all xml comments goes into xml file specified in VS interface (project properties->build)

And I can't figure out why some of comments are present in file after build, and some aren't

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us two comments from the same project - one that is included and one that isn't.

Comment: A problem is easier to analize if it contains a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I hadn't noticed that some of classes were in different project.